# Two-in-one image split at mouseover point

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress, slider, mouseover

this is my first post here, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to implement a split "before & after" image (consisting of two images that are split at mouseover point) that responds to mouseover on a WordPress website. I've seen done before, so I know it's possible, but is there any implementation of this that I can easily incorporate (javascript, etc.)? Here's a mock-up video to demonstrate what I mean:

http://youtu.be/j7BtDoxPUnU

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: take this : http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

Comment: Great script, thanks! Is there a way of making it respond to mouseover, rather than having to click it? That would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a small exemple with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/D5LAj/

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use two DIVs that are in the same position (the second one laying on top of the other one). You can achieve this with the style `position: absolute`.

The lower DIV has the image that you want to be on the right side of the split view as its background image. It's size matches the size of the image and remains fixed.

The upper one has the image for the left side as its background image. It's width is constantly adjusted to match the mouse position. The latter is achieved with Javascript by registering a `onmousemove` event.